# Existing touch gestures meaning "create new"?

Tags: touch-screen, gestures

I'm looking for any existing touch gestures that mean "**create new"** (e.g. "create new document", "create new graph", "create new tweet", etc). Can anyone cite any existing "create new" gestures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This movie on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/35693267) displays the [Clear](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clear-tasks-to-do-list/id493136154) iOS app. It demonstrates some gestures that create new items. I'm not saying they are standard, but it may be a start. They seem to have two: pull down, and pinch out.

Answer (score 6):

Gestures that don't mimic real physical interaction are not easily learned. I would suggest you do not use a gesture for this but a button, icon, or text instead.

Questions to ask before introducing a gesture:

1. Am I adding value? Or is it a gimmick?
2. Does this gesture make sense if it were manipulating the physical.
3. How many seconds does this add to the users goal? Both in action and in learning.

Comment: The original question is still valid, this answer should be a comment on the original question

Comment: No, it really shouldn't be a commit as it points out a very valid point of when to use gestures and cite reasons not to make one up for a "non physical" action.  Just because you are in a "gesture environment" does not mean you should have a specific gesture for each action.  A button labeled "create new" is much more intuitive to a user the any gesture you'll create.

Comment: @hammerbrostime Did you see my questions? Do you feel your product requirements passes those? Perhaps expand more on what the product does?

Comment: @evil-closet-monkey I would say jonshariat's answer suggests a general heuristic, but like most heuristics, there are usually exceptions. My question was very pointed and didn't require any specific use cases, BUT lets say a power user wanted a qestural shortcut that could be used anywhere on a app or site... then we've created the gestural equivalent of a keyboard shortcut. Such a gestural shortcut *does not* preclude the existence of a obvious button, icon or text link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a gesture would come with familiarity in using a product, much like keyboard short-cuts on OSX & Windows.

A button should be provided to create new, which can be hidden within an option screen, along with the ability to create the gesture for create new.